# Javascript compare arrays to mark occurrences of a specific element

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I have an array that contains `n` arrays that hold a car information (`color`, `company`) as follows:
`el[0]` -> color value
`el[1]` -> company value

My goal is to show for how many car companies a color can be found.

For example this array

```
var array = [
  ['red', 'Ford'],
  ['blue', 'Ford'],
  ['green', 'Ford'],
  ['red', 'Ford'],
  ['red', 'Renault'],
  ['blue', 'Renault'],
  ['green', 'Opel'],
  ['red', 'Opel']
];
```

Should be changed as follows:

```
 result = [
  ['red', 'Ford', '3: Ford, Renault, Opel'],
  ['blue', 'Ford', '2: Ford, Renault'],
  ['green', 'Ford', '2: Ford, Open'],
  ['red', 'Renault', '3: Ford, Renault, Opel'],
  ['blue', 'Renault', '2: Ford, Renault'],
  ['green', 'Opel', '2: Ford, Opel'],
  ['red', 'Opel', '3: Ford, Renault, Opel']
 ];
```

Explanation:
There are `3` companies having the `red` color: `Ford, Renault, Opel`
There are `2` companies having the `blue` color: `Ford, Renault`
There are `2` companies having the `green` color: `Ford, Opel`

This is how I think it can be solved, but I'm not sure if it's the right approach:
1. Loop through each array and filter the color to get all companies that apply to it
2. Loop through the filter response and remove the duplicates
3. Loop again through the main array and assign the result from step 2 to the corresponding array that has the filtered color

Comment: And how did you approached this problem? Do you have algorithm in plain English?

Comment: @Learnonhardway I've updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take a double loop approach with a hash table for collecting the second element of the array.

```js
var array = [['red', 'Ford'], ['blue', 'Ford'], ['green', 'Ford'], ['red', 'Ford'], ['red', 'Renault'], ['blue', 'Renault'], ['green', 'Opel'], ['red', 'Opel']],
    hash = Object.create(null);

array.forEach(function (a) {
    hash[a[0]] = hash[a[0]] || {};
    hash[a[0]][a[1]] = true;
});
array.forEach(function (a, i, aa) {
    var keys = Object.keys(hash[a[0]]);
    aa[i][2] = keys.length + ': ' + keys.join(', ');
});

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can approach it like this:

```js
var array = [
  ['red', 'Ford'],
  ['blue', 'Ford'],
  ['green', 'Ford'],
  ['red', 'Ford'],
  ['red', 'Renault'],
  ['blue', 'Renault'],
  ['green', 'Opel'],
  ['red', 'Opel']
];

// To store calculated counts
var cache = {};

var result = array.map(item => {
  var key = item[0];

  // Do processing only if the item isn't found in cache
  if (!cache[key]) {
    var models = array
      // Get all the same colored items
      .filter(item1 => {
        return item1[0] === key;
      })
      // Get the list of models
      .map(item1 => {
        return item1[1];
      })
      // Extract only the unique values
      .filter((item1, i, arr) => {
        return arr.indexOf(item1) === i;
      });

    // Put the calculation in cache
    if (!cache[key]) {
      cache[key] = `${models.length}: ${models.join(', ')}`;
    }
  }

  // Append the result into original item
  item.push(cache[key]);
  
  return item;
});

console.log(result);
```

I have used an intermediary object `cache` to save some processing time, since the same operation has to be done a number of times for a color.

Answer (score 0):

You can build an associative array-like object where you store a list of car by color. You can then map the original array by changing it's elements by using the associative-array-like object:

```js
var array = [
  ['red', 'Ford'],
  ['blue', 'Ford'],
  ['green', 'Ford'],
  ['red', 'Ford'],
  ['red', 'Renault'],
  ['blue', 'Renault'],
  ['green', 'Opel'],
  ['red', 'Opel']
];

var map = array.reduce((map, row) => {
    map[row[0]] = map[row[0]] || [];
    if (!map[row[0]].includes(row[1])) {
        map[row[0]].push(row[1]);
    }
    return map;
}, {});

var result = array.map(row => (row.push(`${map[row[0]].length}: ${map[row[0]].join(', ')}`), row));

console.log(result);
```

In a more readable way:

```js
var array = [
  ['red', 'Ford'],
  ['blue', 'Ford'],
  ['green', 'Ford'],
  ['red', 'Ford'],
  ['red', 'Renault'],
  ['blue', 'Renault'],
  ['green', 'Opel'],
  ['red', 'Opel']
];

var map = array.reduce((map, row) => {
    var [ color, car ] = row;
    map[color] = map[color] || [];
    if (!map[color].includes(car)) {
        map[color].push(car);
    }
    return map;
}, {});

var result = array.map(row => { 
    var [ color, car ] = row;
    row.push(`${map[color].length}: ${map[color].join(', ')}`);
    return row;
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var array = [
  ['red', 'Ford'],
  ['blue', 'Ford'],
  ['green', 'Ford'],
  ['red', 'Ford'],
  ['red', 'Renault'],
  ['blue', 'Renault'],
  ['green', 'Opel'],
  ['red', 'Opel']
];

const res = array.map(set => {
  const newSet = set;
  const same = array.filter(compareSet => set[0] === compareSet[0])
    .map(compareSet => compareSet[1])
    .filter((make, i, arr) => arr.indexOf(make) === i);
  newSet.push(`${same.length} ${same.join(', ')}`);
  return newSet;
});

document.body.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(res).split('],[').join('], <br/>[');
```